# How to enable HTTPS for standalone Wiremock for json API request

Tags: json, localhost, wiremock

I have configured **standalone wire mock (2.21.0)** in my server with **(local host) (Port -8080 )**  while trying to access the URL locally it is working fine but when configured end point URL its getting error. How to access the Local host URL on public? I am  new at this.

```
{
 "id" : "76ada7b0-49ae-4229-91c4-396a36f18e09",
  "request" : {
        "method" : "GET",
        "url" : "/api/mytest"
    },

"response" : {
        "status": 200,
        "headers" : {
           "Content-Type" : "application/json",
           "CorrelationId_T" : "1234321098890",
            "ActivityName_T" : "VoucherRedeem",
            "MsgType_T" : "RESPONSE",
            "Priority_T": "1",
             "Source" : "CRM",
             "MessageId" : "subscriberId",
              "Timestamp" : "2018-01-20T13:27:48.088Z",
"Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cache-Control" : "no-cache",
"Host" : "localhost:8888",
"Pragma" : "no-cache",
"Proxy-Connection" : "keep-alive",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1",
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" }

},
"uuid" : "76ada7b0-49ae-4229-91c4-396a36f18e09"

    }

{
 "id" : "76ada7b0-49ae-4229-91c4-396a36f18e09",
  "request" : {
        "method" : "GET",
        "url" : "/api/mytest"
    },

"response" : {
        "status": 200,
        "headers" : {
           "Content-Type" : "application/json",
           "CorrelationId_T" : "1234321098890",
            "ActivityName_T" : "VoucherRedeem",
            "MsgType_T" : "RESPONSE",
            "Priority_T": "1",
             "Source" : "CRM",
             "MessageId" : "subscriberId",
              "Timestamp" : "2018-01-20T13:27:48.088Z",
"Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cache-Control" : "no-cache",
"Host" : "localhost:8888",
"Pragma" : "no-cache",
"Proxy-Connection" : "keep-alive",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1",
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" }

},
"uuid" : "76ada7b0-49ae-4229-91c4-396a36f18e09"

    }
```

Comment: Usually it helps quite a lot if you tell what the error is